# Working with very large objects

Tags: modeling, objects

Hi so I was wondering I am thinking of making a space ship for my game but I would want it be rather large around 350m long and have versus floor so my question is , based on my understanding if I want to make that to scale in blender I would need to make it in separate parts ? or should I make it smaller and then enlarge it in my game engine ?

Comment: You could make that in Blender no problem even if you modelled it in millimeters. But I'd suggest a scale of 1 Blender unit = 1 meter, that is the standard in game engines like Unity.

Comment: You can change the clipping distance for the viewport and for cameras, so there is theoretically no limit to size.

Comment: Additionally to the suggestion offered by @NᴏᴠɪᴄᴇIɴDɪsɢᴜɪsᴇ, there is a clipping adjustment in the camera settings of the object properties for lenses, shown in [this image](http://my.core.com/B9/E2/mjolnir/photos/Blender_Uploads/Blender_lens_clipping.jpg), with the setting location shown boxed in red, on the tab boxed in yellow..

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to make it separate parts due to scale, but it is probably wise to break something like a spaceship into different parts (depending on the level of detail...more detail = more parts).

If your game engine is Unity (and most likely even if it isn't), you will want to use 1m = 1bu (blender unit) or switch to meters here:

[image]

As NoviceInDisguise mentioned in the comments, you may want to adjust the clipping distance in the 3D view if you are working with unusually large or small objects.

[image]

Comment: Besides changing the scale to metric you might also want to change the **Unit Scale** when dealing with very large objects, so that instead of working on meters you can deal with 10m, 100m or Km depending on your needs. It is also worth noting that besides the scale for the scene you can control the **scale for the viewport independently**, so that the floor grid accommodates your needs (the controls are on the display>Grid Floor>Scale) Also keep in mind that the clipping points for the scene and the camera are different controls.